# Why is this local var not set correctly according to ChiselTest

Tags: chisel, chiseltest

I'm coming from Bluespec and not understanding this Chisel behavior.   I have a simple Module:

```
class WhyFails extends Module {
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val operation = Input(UInt(2.W))
        val result = Output(UInt(32.W))
        val invalidOperation = Output(Bool())
    })

    var invalidOperation = false.B
    when (io.operation === 0.U) {
        io.result := 99.U
        printf("WF: Valid operation\n")
    }
    .otherwise {
        io.result := 0.U
        invalidOperation = true.B
        printf("WF: Invalid operation\n")
    }

    io.invalidOperation := invalidOperation
}
```

I'm trying to decipher why my tester is indicating the io.invalidOperation is asserted in this test.

```
class WhyFailsTest extends AnyFlatSpec with ChiselScalatestTester {
    behavior of "WhyFails"

    it should "Not Fail?" in {
        test(new WhyFails) { wf =>
            wf.io.operation.poke(0.U)
            wf.clock.step() // Step so printf() produces output
            wf.io.invalidOperation.expect(false.B)
            wf.io.result.expect(99.U)
        }
    }
}
```

The output (notice the printf indicating the valid operation)

```
> test
WF: Valid operation
[info] WhyFailsTest:
[info] WhyFails
[info] - should Not Fail? *** FAILED ***
[info]   io_invalidOperation=true (1, 0x1) did not equal expected=false (0, 0x0) (lines in WhyFailsTest.scala: 11) (WhyFailsTest.scala:16)
...<snip>...
[info] *** 1 TEST FAILED ***
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         temp.WhyFailsTest
[error] (Test / test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jun 3, 2022, 8:59:04 AM
```

If I instead assign io.invalidOperation directly (instead of the local var), everything works.  Why is the behavior with the local var different than assigning directly to io.invalidOperation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want do declare a new wire, you may try this:

```
val invalidOperation = Wire(Bool())
io.invalidOperation := invalidOperation
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I modified the code as indicated and it returned the same error.   :-(

Comment: Following up:  it turns out @YudeWei is correct.   After I made their change, I neglected to change the 'invalidOperation = false.B' to 'invalidOperation := false.B'.   Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: You would need an `invalidOperation := false.B` in (should also work if above) the when block. Within the otherwise statement it should be `:=` and not `=`. I'll write up an answer when I get the chance explaining more on the why, but hardware constructs should be immutable `val` instead of `var` and the `:=` operator is used to make connections to those hardware constructs.